# Vue.js transition class disappearing before animation has finished

Tags: animation, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have create a Vue component that uses a javascript hook as a transition to call velocity.js and animate my components.

https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KiUnEo0HaCp3J4nQ9Gw

The `slideDown` of the component works fine. However when the `v-on:leave` kicks in. It seems the display CSS property is set to `display: none` immediately therefore my `slideUp` animation is not shown.

I guess this happens because the transition animation duration is not known therefore is simply toggles between display `none` and `block`.

How can I possible fix this though?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AccordionItem.vue, since you are not using CSS for your transitions, you need to accept a callback from Vue and have Velocity inform it when the transition is complete.

Simply:

```
leave(e, done) {
  Velocity(e, 'slideUp', { duration: 250, complete: done });
}
```

You can see it working [here](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KiUywYIjxDI8o19r9bY)

This [section](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks) of the Vue docs explains:

> When using JavaScript-only transitions, the `done` callbacks are required for the `enter` and `leave` hooks. Otherwise, they will be called synchronously and the transition will finish immediately.

Comment: Read over that part, thanks for helping out! This works brilliantly.